# Download entire web pages and save them as html file with urllib.request

Tags: web-scraping, html

I can save multiple web pages with using these codes; however, I cant see a proper website view after saving them as html. For example, the texts in table are slipped and images can't be seen. 
I need to download entire pages just as we do save as in any web browser so that I can see a proper view.

```
import urllib.request

url= 'https://asd.com/asdID='
for i in range(1, 5):
    print('     --> ID:', i)
    newurl = url + str(i)
    f = open(str(i)+'.html', 'w')
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(newurl)
    pagetext = str(page.read())
    f.write(pagetext)
    f.close()
```

Comment: when you get a webpage you just get HTML code of that page. To download assets like images, scripts, style-sheets etc you need to extract corresponding links in that HTML code and download them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium instead to download full website nicely
Just run the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
#Download the chrome driver from the link below and specify the path of chromedriver
#https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/
chromedriver = 'C:/python36/chromedriver.exe'
url= 'https://asd.com/asdID='
for i in range(1, 5):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get(url + str(i))
    data = browser.page_source
    with open("webpage%s.html" %(str(i)), "w+") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

UPDATE

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import ahk

firefox = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
from selenium import webdriver

driver = web.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox)
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
ahk.start()
ahk.ready()
ahk.execute("Send,^s")
ahk.execute("WinWaitActive, Save As,,2")
ahk.execute("WinActivate, Save As")
ahk.execute("Send, C:\\path\\to\\file.htm")
ahk.execute("Send, {Enter}")
```

You will now get everything

Comment: Please comment if you are facing any problem

Comment: How can I merge all these html documents into one html document?

Comment: What is the point in merging all html documents to one.If you merge all html docements intoone then you cannot open your respective web pages later

Comment: Actually, I'd like to see all information in one document. I will convert then this html document to docx format. 'ahk' is not usable in python 3. What is the alternative way? And should 'web.Firefox' be 'webdriver.Firefox'?

Comment: yeah it should be webdriver.and to merge all documents into 1,you need to chang     
    with open("webpage%s.html" %(str(i)), "w+") as f:
        f.write(data)                                                                                                        to     with open("webpage.html" , "a") as f:
        f.write(data)